# setting up my mysql table properley

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I'm after some input on how would be best to set-up my mySQL table.

The table in question is a table which stores information about advertisements posted onto my site. Most of the columns are simple, and contain all the usual info like price, userID of whoever submitted, date submitted etc.

The part I'm having problems with is the photos. Any number of photos can be added to an advert, from minimum 1 to potentially unlimited (although, I would cap it at some point, but realistically it could be up to 40).

Currently, I have 1 'photos' column, where I store all the photos paths, separated by commas.

To start, I have been told this isn't best practice.

Also, it makes deleting a single photo from a listing with a 'delete' button on the site fairly long winded; I have to get the commma separated list, explode it, find the bit that matches the image I want to delete and delete it, put the list back together and re-insert it into the same field again.

Presumably the answer is a column for each photo, somehow created dynamically as its needed? but I'm not sure how this would work, in terms of code to add a column (via php on insert), but also, 1 row may have 30 photos, and another only 1, so the row with 1 will have 29 empty columns? is this bad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a column for each photo, why don't you try with a table for photos:

TB_PHOTO
id (INT)
path (VARCHAR)
userId (referenced to the table of the user)

Then you can retrieve the data for your photo, and all the photos you want. For example

```
select path from TB_PHOTO where userId='?';
```

And you will get all the photos that belong to a specific user.

Comment: accepted as first to answer, but both answers helpful, thank you both!

Answer (score 1):

This is what's called an *1-to-n* relationship.  And you're correct, the approach you're taking isn't a good one, it will lead to many headaches down the road.  Do a quick Google search for "database normalization" and you'll find lots of info on the topic. Must-read stuff.

Your approach: remove the `photos` columns from you ads table, and introduce an additional `ads_photos` table.  That table will have at least two columns, an `ad_id` column which references the ad to which a photo belongs, and something like a `url` column that has the URL of the photo.

This allows you to associate any number of photos with a given ad.  I'd suggest using InnoDB tables to enable the use of "real" foreign key relationships between the tables.